# Si hay que poner una palabra abreviada antes de dos puntos, ¿se debe poner un punto?

Tags: puntuación, abreviaturas

El ejemplo es fácil, tengo que escribir "Velocidad mínima" abreviado, así: "Velocidad mín.", pero justo después tengo que hacer una enumeración.

¿Qué versión es correcta y por qué?

- Velocidad mín.:
- Velocidad mín:

Answer (score 7):

Aunque la RAE tiene varias páginas dedicadas a la las [abreviaturas](http://www.rae.es/diccionario-panhispanico-de-dudas/apendices/abreviaturas), quizá sea más significativa [esta entrada](http://www.rae.es/diccionario-de-la-lengua-espanola/sobre-la-22a-edicion-2001/abreviaturas-y-signos-empleados) sobre las abreviaturas usadas en el propio DRAE. En el tercer punto de esta página vemos

> Toda abreviatura a la que se posponga una -s pasa a designar el mismo concepto, pero expresado en plural (**p. ej.,** «exprs.» ‘expresiones’, «locs.» ‘locuciones’, etc.).

Se abrevia "por ejemplo" a "p. ej." y después viene una coma. Daría igual que fuese otro signo de puntuación. El punto después de `ej` forma parte de la abreviatura, pero no cuenta como un punto y seguido o un punto y aparte, por ejemplo <sup>*</sup>. Así que puedes usar los dos puntos después del signo, igual que la RAE usa la coma en ese ejemplo.

<sup>*</sup>Mira también la entrada [sobre el uso del punto](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=PxrAnmVfND6FK0uGdT), donde se explica que

> 3.3. Si el punto de una abreviatura coincide con el punto de cierre del enunciado, solo debe escribirse un punto, nunca dos: *A la boda fueron todos sus parientes: tíos, primos, sobrinos, etc. Fueron en total ciento veinte invitados.*

Comment: Gracias, daríamos por válido `mín.:` en este caso pues, ya que el punto forma parte de la palabra, y no se interpreta como signo de puntuación.

Comment: Falta decir, en respuesta a la pregunta del tïtulo, que no sólo se puede, sino que se *debe*.

Answer (score 5):

Creo que [esta es la sección del panhispánico de dudas](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=abreviatura) que es más pertinente para la cuestión planteada:

> Si una abreviatura coincide con final de oración o de párrafo, el punto de la abreviatura sirve de punto final, de modo que solo se escribirá un punto y no dos. Los otros signos de puntuación (coma, punto y coma, puntos suspensivos, signo de interrogación, etc.) sí deben escribirse tras el punto de la abreviatura; por lo tanto, si tras una abreviatura hay puntos suspensivos, se escriben cuatro puntos (...)